# Vue.js - Displays incorrectly in Safari

Tags: vue.js, safari

I am working on one web application and learning Vue.js in parallel.
My site working correctly on Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but in Safari layout is moving around.

Myb .browserslistrc

```
> 1%
last 3 year
not dead
not ie 11
```

npx browserslist displays the correct list of browsers, including Safari, but it doesn't work fine.

What could be the problem?

- I tried changing .browserslistrc
- adding -webkit-box options to css

Answer (score 0):

Generally understood.
The problem was not with Safari support per se, but with the non-working popup window setting

```
display: flex.
```

Changed to

```
display: table
```

and it worked